# Why does it always only show the first alert?

Tags: swift, if-statement, uialertview

I want to make a register view and for that I want to make two fields for a password. The first field to choose a password and the second to confirm it. And I also want to check if the Email address is a Email address. I want to be able to log in. The App will only be for my friends.
The Problem is, that no matter what I put in the textfields it always show the first alert.

Can someone help me what I've done wrong?

```
@IBAction func register(sender: AnyObject) {

    if RegisterPassword1 != RegisterPassword2 {
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Fehler"
        alert.message = "Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
    } else if ListOfAllEmail.contains(RegisterEmailadress.text!) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UserIdentified", sender: self)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Fehler"
        alert.message = "Emailadresse steht nicht im Rodel!"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is RegisterPassword1/2?

Comment: Where `RegisterPassword1` and `RegisterPassword2` come from?

Comment: RegisterPassword1 and RegisterPassword2 are the UITextfields where the user can write his password into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare not `UITextFields`, but text in it

```
if RegisterPassword1.text != RegisterPassword2.text {

}
```

and you should give them names like `registerPasswordOneTextField` and `registerPasswordTwoTextField`

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot for your quick answer, I will remember your tip

Comment: all tips are described in Complete Code :)